# Google Search Appliance: com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: The TCP/IP connection to the host "xyz" port 1433 has failed.

Tags: sql-server, jdbc, tcp, connector, google-search-appliance

I'm deploying google search appliance connector for database(SQL). When I run my "run.bat", I got an error in my logs which says:

```
 java.io.IOException: com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: The TCP/IP connection to the host "xyz", port 1433 has failed. Error: "null. Verify the connection properties. Make sure that an instance of SQL Server is running on the host and accepting TCP/IP connections at the port. Make sure that TCP connections to the port are not blocked by a firewall.".
    at com.google.enterprise.adaptor.database.DatabaseAdaptor.getDocIds(DatabaseAdaptor.java:235)
    at com.google.enterprise.adaptor.DocIdSender.pushFullDocIdsFromAdaptor(DocIdSender.java:69)
    at com.google.enterprise.adaptor.GsaCommunicationHandler$PushRunnable.run(GsaCommunicationHandler.java:856)
    at com.google.enterprise.adaptor.OneAtATimeRunnable.run(OneAtATimeRunnable.java:69)
    at com.google.enterprise.adaptor.ShutdownWaiter$NotificationRunnable.run(ShutdownWaiter.java:183)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
```

I have tried the below solutions:

1. Remove All the TCP Dynamic Ports and Add value of 1433 to all TCP Port and restart your SQL Server.
   My SQL Server Configuration looks like this:

[image]

[image]

[image]

2. Check the value of key TcpDynamicPorts. 
   [image]

I don't have my dynamic port set.

Is there any other way to solve this error. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Check your firewall

Comment: Yes, turn off your Windows Firewall completely to test.

Comment: Does turning off the Firewall will completely solve this problem? I'm working on a project, I don't have permission to do that. I will ask my client for that @TerryChambers-Onix

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that all TCP Dynamic ports are set to 0 and TCP Ports is blank on all except IPALL which your current setting is correct.

It looks like a communication problem between your application server and the SQL Server.  I would suggest checking the port using TELNET in a CMD window with either the IP Address of the SQL server or domain name.

`TELNET pc.name.com 1433`

or

```
TELNET 172.0.0.1 1433
```

If you get a blank screen after this you were successful and the port is open.  If not, there is a firewall or network setting blocking the connection.

Comment: I used the command "TELNET IP_ADDRESS 1433" and I got a blank screen which means that the port is open. But still, I am getting the same errors in my logs which say: Verify the connection properties. Make sure that an instance of SQL Server is running on the host and accepting TCP/IP connections at the port. I haven't turned off the firewall connection on my SQL Server.

Comment: Great!  That tells us that the port is open.  I would now suggest looking at the security aspect.  Check and see what account is trying to connect to the SQL instance.  If it is a SQL account or Windows account.  Check the database you are connecting to and make sure that it has permission to access it.

Comment: My firewall connection is off now. In the incoming connections section it says "Block all the connections to the programs that are not on the list of the allowed programs". Should I add the IP address of my application server in TCP/IP properties and enabled it?

Comment: If you can add trusted connections on the network or on the server, then yes.

Comment: There is one section under Windows firewall: Allow programs to communicate through Windows Firewall. (http://www.dummies.com/computers/operating-systems/windows-7/how-to-allow-programs-through-the-windows-7-firewall/). which program should I select?

Comment: Unfortunately I'm a DBA not a Windows / Network guy.  The servers that I use do not have Windows firewalls working at all and everything is done on the network level through our routers.  My best answer is to try them and see which works.

Comment: You are very welcome.  Sorry I couldn't give you a specific answer at this level.